# Preventing a Duplicate value INSERT in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, merge

My goal is to prevent inserting duplicate data by checking for existing value in a column prior to insert. This would be the same effect as using an 'IF NOT EXISTS ()...' in MS SQL.

I am unable to accomplish this in Oracle 11g. I understand Oracle PLSQL does not provide the same statements to do so. Please correct my understanding.

In my research I've found that 'MERGE' is a way to accomplish this goal.

My PLSQL is below, however does not work. Query results in "0 rows merged"

The EMP Table does have IDENTITY COLUMN of ID which is represented in the table below.

```
MERGE INTO EMP E
USING 
(SELECT ID, EMAIL FROM EMP WHERE EMAIL = 'test@email.com') T
ON (E.EMAIL = T.EMAIL)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT  
(
  F_NAME
  , L_NAME 
  , EMAIL
)
VALUES
(
  'Employee'
  , 'Test'
  , 'ZZZZ@email.com'
);
COMMIT;
```

A representation of the EMP Table is below

```
"EMP" TABLE
    ID       F_NAME          L_NAME          EMAIL
    -------  ------------    ------------    ------------
    1        John            Smith           test@email.com
```

My attempts at using IF NOT EXISTS is below. Both proc and query work well in MS SQL, but produces syntax errors after the IF statement in Oracle 11g:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SPADDUPDATEEMP" 
(
  P_FNAME IN EMP.F_NAME%TYPE
  , P_LNAME IN EMP.L_NAME%TYPE
  , P_EMAIL IN EMP.EMAIL%TYPE
)
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMAIL = P_EMAIL)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO EMP
(
  F_NAME
  , L_NAME
  , EMAIL
)
VALUES
(
  P_FNAME
  , P_LNAME
  , P_EMAIL
)
END;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: You are trying to merge `EMP` using `EMP` ?? of course wont merge because the email already on the table. And you dont have a section for the `MATCH` cases

Comment: Oracle and SQL Server do in fact have nearly identical syntax and functions for this kind of query.  Just use the same query you used in SQL Server on Oracle.  If that doesn't work then show us the query and the error you get, it usually can be fixed with very minor changes.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I will investigate the MERGE statement further to better understand it's construct. The purpose was to MERGE when the email addresses did not match.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in the question. Only plain SQL

Comment: @RBarryYoung added IF NOT EXISTS with error I receive as I now understand this can be accomplished both ways.

Comment: @a_hourse_with_no_name stored procedures are PL/SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the same like the marked answer but with a merge statement you should rewrite you query in that way:

```
MERGE INTO EMP E
USING 
(SELECT 'Employee'       AS F_NAME
       ,'Test'           AS L_NAME
       ,'ZZZZ@email.com' AS EMAIL 
   FROM dual ) T
ON (E.EMAIL = T.EMAIL)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT  
(
   F_NAME
  ,L_NAME 
  ,EMAIL
)
VALUES
(
   T.F_NAME
  ,T.L_NAME
  ,T.EMAIL
);
```

Answer (score 5):

maybe something like this?

```
ALTER TABLE EMP ADD CONSTRAINT NO_DUPLICATE UNIQUE(ID,F_NAME,L_NAME,EMAIL);
```

[Source](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/unique.php)

Comment: This will raise an error. Doesnt solve the problem. You want provide an insert avoiding this problem

Comment: This will prevent duplicate inserts on Primary Key. I'm using increment function to prevent this. My goal is to prevent duplicate data being inserted.

Comment: You can add a unique constraint on any field.  It would be the only way to ensure no duplicates in the column.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO emp(
  F_NAME
  , L_NAME 
  , EMAIL
)
SELECT 
    'Employee'
  , 'Test'
  , 'ZZZZ@email.com'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM emp WHERE EMAIL = 'ZZZZ@email.com'
);
```

Comment: Perfect. Marked as answer.